# Dynamic Query is not passing in test class

Tags: apex

[image]Here is my Apex Code

```
public class Lookup {

    /*This method is called from LC*/
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String searchDB(String objectName, String fld_API_Text, String fld_API_Val, 
                                  Integer lim,String fld_API_Search,String searchText ){

                                      searchText='\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchText.trim()) + '%\'';


                                      String query = 'SELECT '+fld_API_Text+' ,'+fld_API_Val+
                                          ' FROM '+objectName+
                                          ' WHERE '+fld_API_Search+' LIKE '+searchText+ 
                                          ' LIMIT '+lim;
                                      List<ResultWrapper> lstRet = new List<ResultWrapper>();
                                      try{
                                          System.debug('==17==');
                                          List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query(query);
                                          System.debug('==18=='+sobjList.size());
                                          ResultWrapper obj = new ResultWrapper();
                                          for(SObject s : sobjList){
                                               obj = new ResultWrapper();
                                              obj.objName = objectName;
                                              obj.text = String.valueOf(s.get(fld_API_Text)) ;
                                              obj.val = String.valueOf(s.get(fld_API_Val))  ;
                                              lstRet.add(obj);
                                          } 
                                      }catch(Exception ex){

                                          ex.getMessage();
                                      }
                                      return JSON.serialize(lstRet) ;
                                  }
    /* Wrapper Class*/
    public with sharing class ResultWrapper{
        public String objName {get;set;}
        public String text{get;set;}
        public String val{get;set;}
    }
}
```

---

This is my test class

```
@isTest
public class LookupTest {

    static testMethod void test1(){
        Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeInfo = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Schema.RecordTypeInfo rec = recordTypeInfo.get('Retailer');
        string recordTypeIdRetailer = rec.getRecordTypeId();
        List<Account> acList = new List<Account>(); 
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.Name='test demo';
        ac.RecordTypeId =recordTypeIdRetailer;
        ac.Class_of_Trade__c='Liquor';
        acList.add(ac);
        insert acList;
        Lookup.ResultWrapper wrap = new Lookup.ResultWrapper();
        wrap.objName='sObject';
        wrap.text='Name';
        wrap.val='Name';
        Lookup.searchDB('Account','Name','Name',2,'test demo','test demo');
    }
}
```

My Test class is not covering the loop.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should never swallow exceptions like this:

```
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

Your test should be failing loudly because your query is throwing an exception. Instead, you've hidden that exception with a useless `catch` block, and thereby made your debugging considerably harder - and potentially risked users' trust. It's concealed from you the fact that you don't have a code coverage problem - you have a failing test!

The exception is thrown because you run this query:

```
String query = 'SELECT '+fld_API_Text+' ,'+fld_API_Val+
    ' FROM '+objectName+
    ' WHERE '+fld_API_Search+' LIKE '+searchText+ 
    ' LIMIT '+lim;
```

where both `fld_API_Text` and `fld_API_Val` are equal to `Name`.

```
Lookup.searchDB('Account','Name','Name',2,'test demo','test demo');
```

This results in a `QueryException`.

Consider using different field names and/or building logic into your class to handle this specific circumstance.

You should also be writing assertions against the results of your code to validate its behavior. If you had written an assertion here about what the return value of `Lookup.searchDB()` was, it would be failing, and helping you identify the problem.

Comment: David I am not getting the exception.I am just not able to pass that for loop.What change should I make in my code to get the coverage.

Comment: Which field name I can use here David

Comment: I don't know what your application is intended to do. You should select fields that are representative of how this functionality is intended to work.

Comment: Thanks David Your Suggestion Worked.